# Next js 13 App router build error. (when i try fetch api route in server component)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, next.js, app-router

I get an error when i build next app (yarn run build)

I made new clean project i tried there.
This is my route (/api/categories/route.ts)

```
export async function GET() {
  return new Response(JSON.stringify({ msg: "categories" }));
}
```

And my /page.tsx:

```
export default async function Home() {
  const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/categories");
  console.log(await res.json());

  return (
    <main>
      <h1>Home</h1>
    </main>
  );
}
```

When i run dev app (yarn run dev) i dont have any errors but when i try build i get this error:

[image: error]

I tried also fetch data from fake data json api that i found in web and it worked perfect. But when i try to use my api routes i have an error.

And i tried to change url like: /api/categories and http://127.0.0.1/api/categories

Is there any way I can solve this problem? Because i want to deploy my app.

But when i use prisma in project and i tried to fetch data from prisma exact in page.tsx like: prisma.categories.findMany(...), i dont have problem. But i want thet code will be clean, i have many options for findMay(). So maybe you know how i can solve this without using prisma right in page.tsx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can’t use local api routes to fetch data in server components because api routes are not available at build time. Unfortunately, it’s a limitation in current version of Next.is that I hope will be addressed in future versions.

Comment: Then what can we do as of now?

Comment: been stuck in this issue since 3 days, do you know what can I do to overcome this problem ?

Answer (score 2):

You actually don't need to call local api from a server component. The purpose of a server component is to be rendered on the server and then served to end user on page request.
So you can directly read data from any source of database safely inside a server component.

Answer (score 2):

For now as of NextJs 13, what we can do is to make an export function with the server logic(e.g. to fetch data from database) in a separate file and use that function in **both** the api route as well as the page.js or whichever place (which is being rendered on server).

This way it will prevent the error while building.

**The reason:**

No API routes are served while doing **npm run build**

This will probably get fixed in a future version or someday.